# Robot framework got error: Invalid syntax in test case '...': Using '...' as test case name is deprecated

Tags: robotframework

I got error messages "Invalid syntax in test case '...': Using '...' as test case name is deprecated. It will be considered line continuation in Robot Framework 3.2." in test case but I can use '...' to continue line in variables.

```
*** Test Cases *** 
Check if else
    Open Browser  http://www.google.com  Chrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    ${getText}=  Get Text  name=btnK
    ${msg} =  Create List     ${EMPTY}  Test1  Test2
    log to console  ${msg}[0]
    run keyword if   '${getText}' == '${msg}[1]'  Test Input Text1
...  ELSE IF  '${getText}' == '${msg}[2]'   Test Input Text2
...  ELSE IF  '${getText}' == '${msg}[0]'   Test Input Text3
...  ELSE  Close Browser

But it work in variable file.

*** Variables ***
&{Login}    username=id=username
...     password=id=password
...     submit_button=id=Login
```

Could anyone explain me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an indentation issue.Enter 4 spaces prior to ...

```
Check if else
    Open Browser  http://www.google.com  Chrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    ${getText}=  Get Text  name=btnK
    ${msg} =  Create List     ${EMPTY}  Test1  Test2
    log to console  ${msg}[0]
    run keyword if   '${getText}' == '${msg}[1]'  Test Input Text1
    ...  ELSE IF  '${getText}' == '${msg}[2]'   Test Input Text2
    ...  ELSE IF  '${getText}' == '${msg}[0]'   Test Input Text3
    ...  ELSE  Close Browser
```